# Merging series of raster layers pairwise in QGIS based on same date

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, merge, batch

I have a series of satellite images from different time periods. For each date, I have two adjacent images that I want to merge. The layer names contain the datetime information, based on which the two layers to be merged should be selected: I want to merge each pair of raster layers with the same date.

This can be done manually with `Menu Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge`. However, this is cumbersome as I have to repeat the process for each date/layer pair separately. Is there an easy way to automatize this using QGIS?

The layer names look like in these patterns:

```
 - 37_38_NDVI_YYYYMMDD to be merged with 38_39_NDVI_YYYYMMDD (general rule)
 - 37_38_NDVI_20120402 to be merged with 38_39_NDVI_20120402 (example 1)
 - 37_38_NDVI_20180715 to be merged with 38_39_NDVI_20180715 (example 2)
 - 37_38_NDVI_20211122 to be merged with 38_39_NDVI_20211122 (example 3)
```

*This question was [asked originally by another user](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435405/is-there-a-way-to-mosaic-two-images-of-the-same-date-automatically-in-qgis), but was deleted before I could post my answer - so I post the question here to have a place where to post the answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run either [Merge](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#merge) or [Virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#build-virtual-raster) in [batch mode](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html) (see also [here for batch processing](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html)). To define input layers/ run the tool separately for each pair of layers with the same date, use `Autofill... > Add Values by Expression...` and add the following expression. It will add a new row for each pair of raster layers with the same date so that all these pairs will be merged together.

How the expression works:

1. Create an array of all layer using the variable `@layers` (line 3), keep only the distinct ones (to avoid repeated merging like of a with b and of b with a).
2. Based on this, get the name of the raster layer with `layer_property` and cut the layer name to the 8 characters at the end of the name (lines 6 and 8). If you have other name patterns with the date in another place, this can easily be adapted. The result is a string containing just the date like e.g. `20120402`.
3. Re-create the two layer names by concatenating the invariable parts of the layer names with the date from step 2 (lines 5 and 7) and combine these two to an array (line 4):

```
    array_distinct( 
        array_foreach (
            @layers,
            array (
                '37_38_NDVI_'  || 
                right (layer_property (@element,'name'), 8),
                '38_39_NDVI_'  || 
                right (layer_property (@element,'name'), 8)
            )
        )
    )
```

[image]